# Gnu make "clean" only removes .c files in OBJ/ASM variables

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am trying to **remove all** .o , .i , .asm , .d files stored in variables in this form :

```
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
PP := $(SRCS:.c=.i)
ASM := $(SRCS:.c=.asm)
DEP := $(SRCS:.c=.d)
```

using this code :

```
SRCS = text1.c\
       text2.c
      

OBJS :=$(SRCS:.c=.o)
PP := $(SRCS:.c =.i)
ASM := $(SRCS:.c =.asm)
DEP := $(SRCS:.c =.d)


.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(PP) $(ASM) $(DEP)
```

but it only applies the .o to the $(OBJS) like this :

```
rm -f text1.o text2.o text1.c text2.c text1.c text2.c text1.c text2.c
```

I don't understand why it didn't replace *.c files with *.i or *.asm and so on .

I used this to solve it :

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.i *.asm *.d
```

but i am still learning "make" so i would like to know why the first is not working .. thank u in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you've shown us.

Comment: You have erroenous whitespace in your variable assignments. E.g., replace `$(SRCS:.c =.i)` with `$(SRCS:.c=.i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in after the equals otherwise it tries to match with the spaces in the name.

Here is a fixed version:

```
SRCS = text1.c text2.c

OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
PP   := $(SRCS:.c=.i)
ASM  := $(SRCS:.c=.asm)
DEP  := $(SRCS:.c=.d)

# Note this does not match due to the extra space
PP2   := $(SRCS:.c =.i)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(PP) $(ASM) $(DEP)
```

Comment: thank u it worked.. it's kinda annoying how i get these white-space errors as i did get one in my source.mk file  for using taps.

Comment: @MohamedWehba yeah, makefile is notorious for its white space errors...